# Python Intellisense in Visual Studio for Custom DLLs

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, ironpython

I am struggling to get Intellisense working in Visual Studio with Python, using IronPython and Python Tools for Visual Studio.

I am able to reference my DLLs without issue in various ways through clr.AddReference, so that is not a problem.

I have tried the following to get Intellisense to work:

- Rebuilding the DLLs as a strong name and adding them to the GAC
- Putting the DLLs in a "Release" folder and making them available as ["references"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)
- [Creating TLB files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c(v=vs.110).aspx) for the DLLs to make their internals visible
- Creating an XML documentation file for the DLL and putting it in the GAC

No matter what I try, I keep getting

> Unable to resolve "Blah."  IntelliSense may be missing for this module.

At this point I'm running out of ideas and I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing your Intellisense cache?

Comment: I have tried "rebuilding" the Intellisense references AFIAK

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks1ka3t6(v=vs.90).aspx

Delete the .ncb file?

Comment: intellisense is working, it's just not working for my specific DLLs